# How to edit dynamically generated elements in jQuery mobile dialog box using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm working on a **jQuery mobile** project.
I use **Selectmenu** widget which is open a generated dialog when I click on the widget.
The dialog has a close button, and I want to edit it from

```
<a role="button" href="#" class="ui-btn ui-icon-delete">Close</a>
```

to

```
<a role="button" href="#" class="ui-btn ui-icon-delete"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left"></i></a>
```

The problem is I can not do it using **jQuery** because the dialog HTML is generated dynamically so my script has no effect.
I find that people often use **live()** function to bind events to generated elements but in this case I do not have any event to bind.
I also try **"Load"** or **"Ready"** event but no luck, people on Internet say that **live()** does not support those event.
I hope people here can help me. Thank you so much!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21559226/customize-jquery-mobile-close-button-on-selecmenu-dialog

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to replace the `close` text with `<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left"></i>`.  This can be done with at **jQuery Ready.** See code below:

```
$('a .ui-btn .ui-icon-delete').html("<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left"></i>");
```

Comment: Hi, thank you but as I said, jQuery has no effect because the dialog is only generated when I click on the select widget. The time when my page (and my scripts) is first loaded, there is no HTML of that dialog.

Comment: Can you share your jquery code that generates dialog.

Comment: It is at somewhere in the jQuery mobile .js file. But I'm not allowed to modify jQuery mobile source code. I need to use my own scripts.js file to do it.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle of what type of dialog are you using?